# Setting a custom attribute in Exchange 2013

Tags: active-directory

I cannot figure out how to set a custom Attribute in Exchange 2013.

It was under General in Exchange 2010, if memory serves me correctly. I know you can do it in Active Directory if I dig down to the OU and the distribution list is one of the first 2000 or whatever. If I search for the DL, I cannot enter the Attribute there isn't a place for it in that spot.  I've seen some PS scripts but they do not apply to me. I just need to be able to enter the email address of the DL and then enter the Attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The "Custom Attributes" in the Exchange 2013 GUI are as well on the General Tab, see screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Why does mine not have that?

Comment: If you edit one user in ADSI and add some custom attributes there and then wait some time and open it in the Exchange GUI, did you see them there then?